# Adding Columns of SQlite to Arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

How can i add columns of sqlite database into arraylist. I just added it manually i want to get the data of all columns to database and insert it to arraylist here is the code

```
CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr = new ArrayList<CalendarCollection>();
CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new CalendarCollection("2017-03-21", "Sample data"));
```

I want the sample data's to be the two columns of my database.

This is my Model Class

```
package com.mobile.aaron.sync.util;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CalendarCollection {
public String DATE;
public String DESCRIPTION;
public static ArrayList<CalendarCollection> date_collection_arr ;
public CalendarCollection(String date,String description){
    DATE=date;
    DESCRIPTION=description;

}

public String getDATE() {
    return DATE;
}

public String getDESCRIPTION() {
return DESCRIPTION;
}

public void setDESCRIPTION(String DESCRIPTION) {
this.DESCRIPTION = DESCRIPTION;
}

public void setDATE(String DATE) {
this.DATE = DATE;
}
}
```

ALl the help will be appreciated since i am newbie to this Thanks!

Comment: Decided to post your [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269175/storing-data-from-sqlite-to-arraylist) under a new name? The question is certainly better now. One sign of this is you’ve got an answer already, congrats.

Answer (score 1):

In your database handling file write a method to set data to arraylist.
Like this,

```
public ArrayList<CalendarCollection> getData() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        ArrayList<CalendarCollection> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                    CalendarCollection calenderModel = new CalendarCollection();
                    calenderModel.setDATE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Your Date Database Column Name")));
                    calenderModel.setDESCRIPTION(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Your Description Database Column Name")));

                    dataList.add(calenderModel);

                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        close();

        return dataList;
    }
```

This will return arraylist of reqired data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but i have an error this is the error in my logcat `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.mobile.aaron.sync.DBManager.getData()' on a null object reference
                      at com.mobile.aaron.sync.ListViewActivity.onCreate(ListViewActivity.java:44)`  I just add to my ListViewActivity the dbManager.getData to initialize it.

Comment: Please post your full code with erro so i can help you.

Comment: Thanks it worked i just put `CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr = new ArrayList<CalendarCollection>(); CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr = dbManager.getData();` Thanks

Comment: Your welcome @Jones .Please correct this answer so it may be useful for others.